# Android Vectormaster Click Event Adding

Tags: java, android

I am using [vectormaster](https://github.com/harjot-oberai/VectorMaster) to draw an image that contains different parts. I know I can change the color of each part by identifying the pathmodel.

```
 PathModel outline = heartVector.getPathModelByName("outline");
 outline.setStrokeColor(Color.parseColor("#ED4337"));
```

But my question is how can I attach a click event to a pathmodel so that I can change the color of the part when that part is clicked? Thanks for any pointers to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but still worth to answer. May be this helps the others using vectormaster.
I also ran on this problem. My solution was:

a. Attach click event to imageview.

b. Get the drawables and cast it to vectormasterdrawables.

c. find the region using pathmodel.

d. Check if your motionevent x,y contains in this region.

If you need full code, I can post it here.